# Correctly fix Laravel Connecftion.php function 'prepareBindings' to cast boolean as a string 'true' 'false' and not as integer

Tags: laravel, postgresql

~line 610 in src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php there is a method named 'prepareBindings'.

This section

```
elseif (is_bool($value)) {
    $bindings[$key] = (int) $value;
}
```

I keep getting an issue in which Postgresql is not accepting 1/0 as boolean values, so I have to write them out as a string. 'true', 'false'.

I changed it to

```
elseif (is_bool($value)) {
    $bindings[$key] = $value ? 'true' : 'false';
}
```

And it now works, **but** I want to know the correct way to override this method?

Because as of now, as a quick dirty fix I edited the source file itslf.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to override but maybe you don't need to do that, in your query pass string param instead of integer value like:

```
->where('column', '=', '1')
```

Comment: this isn't a solution, think about of my case for example, I have a system with a lot true and false attributes, it's almost the same of rewrite it and this is doesn't make sense transpile a typo of bool to int to do a query.

Comment: I found this on GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/37201#issuecomment-831119891, basically he overrides the DB connection with self-defined. And you can read https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37168 for more information, look like it's going to fix in the next release

Comment: This won't fix it entirely because a lot of what I save is from an object or array, so a boolean gets passed, and would therefore be a pain/unsustainable to convert them all into integers. Checking your links now though.